# How can we use Linux from a small storage pen drive? Does it work on micro-controllers also?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I generally hear that LINUX OS can be downloaded on flash, pen drive (floppy disk?) etc. How we can do that?

I have RHEL 5.4 source code - so how can download it into pen drive and how much space is required?

What other functionality I can add apart from the OS - so that when I boot from that storage device I can make use of them?

Can we download Linux OS into micro-controllers also?

Comment: yes, you can. but I suggest you begin with pre-built image for usb key instead of RHEL

Comment: As of my experience - I currently run some specialised x86 server off 8GB flash drive with Ubuntu on it. The space needed depends on what components you need. Just bear in mind, that speed and lifespan is far less, then one of HDD.

Comment: You are overusing or misusing the word "download".  In some cases you seem to use "download" when you mean *writing* to a flash drive or *booting* Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I generally hear that LINUX OS can be downloaded on flash, pen drive (floppy disk?) etc. How > we can do that?

If you can't get it to work on your own, you can buy a ready made Linux on a USB drive from
a site like http://www.osdisc.com or http://www.cheapbytes.com

Not all PCs, especially older PCs, can boot from the USB Drive.  Even some newer PCs are beginning to ship with security features that can interfere with booting code.  When it does work, you have to find out the proper way to boot the USB drive.  You might have only a few seconds during reboot to enter the right key, or it will boot Windows (if Windows is installed).  The key to get to the BIOS Boot Menu might be delete or escape or F10 or some other key (varies with PC motherboard manufacturer).  A message on the screen that flashes by rather quickly might mention keys you can press.  Boot to a specific device or changing boot order can also often be found in the BIOS setup.

There is a linux utility called `unetbootin` that will create a USB drive that will boot linux.  It does not create a USB boot drive from a source code distribution, but rather from an ISO file representing a live CD or the live CD itself.

Since large USB drives (e.g. 32GB)  are relatively inexpensive, if you want to compare systems or have multiple systems there is a way to have multiple linux and other operating systems on one USB drive and be able to choose which to boot into.  See, for instance, http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ which has a wide variety of procedures for making a bootable USB using either windows or Linux to set up the USB and booting a variety of systems.

> I have RHEL 5.4 source code - so how can download it into pen drive
>   and how much space is required?

RHEL 5.4 is a bit old.  You need the Live CD, if there was one.

The ISO file can take up 600+MB.  You want space left over to use the system.  2GB for the pen drive is OK.  Sometimes you can get by with less.

> What other functionality I can add apart from the OS - so that when I
>   boot from that storage device I can make use of them?

Upon boot the operating system will often recognize sound cards, other usb devices, the hard drives, etc.  You need to know how to use these things within Linux, and how to enable them if they are not configured. Some Linux distributions have a place to put packages that are to be autoinstalled when a USB pen drive based system initializes.  In this way you can "install" software from the distribution archives that are not included on the standard live system, even if you don't have internet access.

> Can we download Linux OS into micro-controllers also?

People run it on raspberry pi and such, but the versions of Linux on non-PC hardware that has low memory are often quite tiny compared to a desktop version.  They can be tiny enough to be challenging to work with or expand.